# jquery datatable - position jquery UI modal below the selected record

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I am following the example given below and able to display jqueryui modal whenever the user clicks on the row in jquery datatable.

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/jqueryui-modal.html

Is there anyway, I can position the modal dialog below the selected row?

Expectation:

[image]

My code:

I am trying to set the position as shown below. But, it is not working as expected. How should I pass / assign the position of the selected datatable record to the jquery UI modal dialog?

```
 responsive: {
            details: {
                display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
                    header: function () {
                        return 'View Record';
                    },
                    dialog: {                        
                        modal: true,
                        width: 800,
                        resizable: false,
                        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: $(tableId) },
                        create: function (event, ui) {

                        },
                        open: function (event, ui) {

                        }
                    }
                }),
```

Any suggestion / recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: What is `$(tableId)`?

Comment: tableId -> is the id of the jquery datatable. $(tableId) -> is the jquery object of it.

Comment: Wouldn't you need `$("#" + tableId)`

Comment: The value of tableId variable is already'#<actual table id>'. Thanks for checking.

Comment: Based on the docs, *...a `modal` option which is an object of configuration parameters that will be passed to the jQuery UI modal.* Should then `dialog` object be called `modal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear from the documentation, yet it seems that the `row` is passed to the header function. I would think that you'd want to target this in your position settings for the dialog. It does not look like you can get to the event object, maybe you can pass the `row` into a variable that can then be passed into the `modal` object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myRow;
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: {
            details: {
                display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                    header: function ( row ) {
                        myRow = row;
                        console.log("My Row:", myRow);
                        return 'View Record';
                    },
                    modal: {
                        modal: true,
                        width: 800,
                        resizable: false,
                        position: {
                            my: "left top",
                            at: "left bottom",
                            of: $(myRow)
                        }
                    }
                } )
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

See more: https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.display

> DataTables API instance for the table in question which is pre-populated with the row that is being acted upon - i.e. the result from `row()`.

Once you see what object or parameters are passed to `myRow`, you may need to adjust your position parameters.